# how to redirect users to iphone-targeted website

Tags: iphone, asp.net-mvc

I just found the [IUI project on google code](http://code.google.com/p/iui/) where you can build websites that look like iPhone apps.

I have an asp.net MVC website already built. When a user clicks on my website from an iPhone, i want to redirect them to another page that is targeted to the iPhone.

how can i do this detection and redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the User Agent. ie the javascript way.

```
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
     if (document.cookie.indexOf("iphone_redirect=false") == -1) window.location = "http://m.url.com";

}
```

Or do it in .net with something like [Mobile Device Browser File](http://mdbf.codeplex.com/).